# TypeScript accessing object though key variable error

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, indexing

I have an object which looks something like this

```
interface atype {
 A: number;
 B: number;
}


const a: atype = {
 A: 1,
 B: 2
}
```

I would like to access the value of a property of `a` depending on a given string with the key. i.e.

```
const val = a.[key]
```

this works but I get the error `Identifier expected.`
now if I try doing

```
const val = a[key]
```

Now I get the error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'atype'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'atype'.

Could someone help me figure out how to do this w/o any errors/warnings

Comment: where is the declaration of key? Please share the function in which you are using `key`

Comment: so I am using a for loop which goes through an array of strings where these strings are the key, so the key is a string

Comment: please add that loop code as well

Comment: If you type the key as `keyof atype`, it won't throw the errors.